# If an open set $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ contains an closed disk, then there is an larger closed disk containing the original one and contained by $U$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $U\subset \Bbb R^2$ be an open set such that the closed disk $\bar{B}(x,1)\subset U$. Then there is $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\bar{B}(x,1+\varepsilon)\subset U$.

It is obvious but I'm not sure how to prove it. If the boundary of $\bar{B}(x,1)$ intersects the boundary of $U$, then I think that the closed disk will not be contained by $U$. So, $\alpha=\inf\{\|t-y\| : t\in \bar{B}(x,1), y\in\partial U\}>0$, then if we choose $\varepsilon=\frac{\alpha}{2}$, it looks like $\bar{B}(x,1+\varepsilon)\subset U$.

But I not quite sure how to explain rigorously why $\alpha>0$. Hope someone could help me. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\ U=\mathbb{R}^2\ $ then any $\ \epsilon $ will do. Otherwise, there exists a sequence $\ \big\{y_n\big\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq U^c\ $ such that $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_n\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha\ $, and since it must be bounded, it must contain a convergent subsequence whose limit $\ y^*\ $ satisfies $\ \inf\big\{\big\|t-y^*\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha\ $. Since $\ U^c\ $ is closed, then $\ y^*\in U^c\ $ and so $\ \inf\big\{\big\|t-y^*\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}\ne0\ $.

**Reply to OP's query below**

By the definition of infimum, for any positive integer $\ n\ $ there must exist $\ y_n\in\partial U\subseteq U^c\ $ and $\ t_n\in\overline{B}(x,1)\ $ such that $\ \big\|t_n-y_n\big\|<\alpha +\frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$
\alpha\le\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_n\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}\le\big\|t_n-y_n\big\|<\alpha +\frac{1}{n}\ ,
$$
so $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_n\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha\ $ by the [sandwich theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973271/proof-of-sandwich-theorem-for-sequences).

Since  $\ \big\|y_n\big\|-\big\|x\big\|-1\le$$\big\|y_n\big\|-\big\|t\big\|\le$$\big\|t-y_n\big\|\ $ for all $\ t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\ $, then
$$
\big\|y_n\big\|\le\big\|x\big\|+1+\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_n\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}\ ,
$$
and since the sequence on the right of this inequality converges to $\ \|x\|+1+\alpha\ $, it must be bounded, and hence so must $\ y_n\ $.

Comment: I want. to ask why there exists a. sequence $\{yn\}$ in $\Bbb R^2 - U$ such that $ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_n\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha\$ and $\{y_n\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Appreciate your clear explanation. I guess the reason why $y^*$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to \infty}\inf\{\|t-y_n\|:  t\in\overline{B}(x,1) \}=\alpha$ is that since $y_{n_k} \to y^*$, for any $t\in \overline{B}(x,1)$, $\lim_{k\to \infty}\|y_{n_k}-t\|=\|y^*-t\|$, where $\{y_{n_k}\}$ is the subsequence converges to $y^*$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k_0\in \Bbb N$ such that for any $k\ge k_0$, $\|t-y_{n_k} \|-\varepsilon<\|t-y^*\|<\|t-y_{n_k}\|+\varepsilon$, then $\alpha-\varepsilon<\|t-y^*\|\le\alpha+\varepsilon$, for any $t\in \overline{B}(x,1)$.

Comment: So $\alpha-\varepsilon\le\inf\{\|t-y^*\|:t\in     \overline{B}(x,1)\}\le\alpha+\varepsilon$, and $\inf\{\|t-y^*\|:t\in     \overline{B}(x,1)\}=\alpha$. Since $\partial U$ is closed $y^*\in \partial U$. I want to ask why this imply $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Because $\ \overline{B}(x,1)\ $ is closed there must be a $\ t^*\in\overline{B}(x,1)\ $ which attains the infimum $\ \alpha=\inf\big\{\big\|t-y^*\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}\ $. That is, $\ \big\|t^*-y^*\big\|=\alpha\ $. But since $\ \partial U\cap\overline{B}(x,1)=\emptyset\ $ (because $ \partial U\subseteq U^c\subseteq\overline{B}(x,1)^c\ $), $\ t^*\in\overline{B}(x,1)\ $, and $\ y^*\in\partial U\ $, then $\ y^*\ne t^*\ $ and so $ \alpha=\big\|t^*-y^*\big\|>0\ $.

Comment: I have reviewed my argument that $y^*$ satisfies that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\inf\{\|t-y^*\|:  t\in\overline{B}(x,1) \}=\alpha$, but I think I'm wrong. I can not conclude $\alpha-\varepsilon<\|t-y^*\|\le\alpha+\varepsilon$ from $\|t-y_{n_k} \|-\varepsilon<\|t-y^*\|<\|t-y_{n_k}\|+\varepsilon$. Do you have any suggestion about it? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Your argument is just missing the step connecting $\ \alpha $ to $\ y_n\ $. By the choice of $\ y_{n_k}\ $, for any $\ \epsilon>0\ $ you must have $\ \alpha\le$$\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_{n_k}\big\|: t\in \overline{B}(x,1)\big\}\le$$\,\alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{4}\ $ and $\ \big\|y_{n_k}-y^*\big\|<$$\ \frac{\epsilon}{2}\ $ for all sufficiently large $\ k\ $.

Comment: Also, there must exist $\ t_k\in\overline{B}(x,1)\ $ such that
\begin{align}
\alpha&\le\big\|t_k-y_{n_k}\big\|\\
&\le\inf\big\{\big\|t_k-y_{n_k}\big\|: t\in \overline{B}(x,1)\big\}+\frac{\epsilon}{4}\\
&\le\alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\ .
\end{align}
 You then have
\begin{align}
\alpha-\epsilon&\le\big\|t_k-y_{n_k}\big\|-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&\le\big\|t_k-y^*\big\|\\
&\le\big\|t_k-y_{n_k}\big\|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&\le\alpha+\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Is there a typo? I think it is $t$ but not $t_k$, $\begin{align} \alpha&\le\big\|t_k-y_{n_k}\big\|\\ &\le\inf\big\{\big\|t-y_{n_k}\big\|: t\in \overline{B}(x,1)\big\}+\frac{\epsilon}{4}\\ &\le\alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\ . \end{align}$ Thanks for your explanation

Comment: After you prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\|t_k-y^* \|=\alpha$, I want to show that $\ \inf\big\{\big\|t-y^*\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha$. Since $\partial U$ is closed, $y^*\in \partial U$, so $\alpha\le \|t-y^*\|$. Since $\lim_{k \to \infty}\|t_k-y^* \|=\alpha$, for any $\varepsilon>0 $, there exists $t_k \in \overline{B}(x,1)$ such that $\|t_k-y^*\|<\alpha + \varepsilon$. Hence, $\ \inf\big\{\big\|t-y^*\big\|: t\in\overline{B}(x,1)\big\}=\alpha$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.