# Show that the sequence $(3n-2)!!!/(3^n\cdot n!)$ converges to $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I came across this sequence while trying to prove that an alternating series converges by Leibniz's test. Here's the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808944/955582) and [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4808997/955582).

Define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as follows. $$a_{n} =\frac{( 3n-2) !!!}{3^{n} \cdotp n!}=\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{7}{9} \cdots \frac{3n-2}{3n}$$

I have shown that it is convergent. Numerically, I found that it converges to $0$... However, I struggled to find the limit. Here's what I did:

Consider the sequence $$b_n=\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{3} +\frac{4}{6} +\frac{7}{9} +\cdots +\frac{3n-2}{3n}\right)\right)^{n}$$

$a_1=b_1$, however, for all $n\geq 2$, $0<a_n<b_n\tag*{}$ (by A.M.-G.M. inequality).

Show that $\lim b_n=0$ and conclude by [sandwich theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973271/proof-of-sandwich-theorem-for-sequences) that $\lim a_n=0$.

$$\begin{aligned}
b_{n} & =\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\left( 1-\frac{2}{3j}\right)\right)^{n}\\
 & =\left( 1-\frac{2}{3n} \cdot \sum _{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\right)^{n}
\end{aligned}$$

$$\color{blue}{\Rightarrow \lim b_n=\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\lim \sum _{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\right)}$$

This is a partial sum sequence of a well-known divergent series.

$$\therefore \lim b_n=\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}x\right)=0$$

**I hope there is no mistake in my approach** though I have doubts about the step which is coloured in blue:

- Is it always justified that $\lim (1+f(n)/n)^n$ will be same as $\lim\exp(f(n))$?

I have done this in high school calculus without giving it much thought, however, I would want to introspect and analyze.

**I would also like to know if there's any alternate yet simpler way to find this limit...**

---

I have also thought of a generalization inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4808991/955582). We can rewrite in terms of binomial coefficients:
$$a_n=\binom{-1/3}{n} (-1)^n$$

I am adding this, in case it's useful.

Comment: Maybe try Sterling's formula.

Comment: @GEdgar I know about Sterling's approximation, but not sure how to apply it in this case. I applied it to the denominator and then I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Method of high school:

Let
$$a_{n}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{7}{9}\cdots\frac{3n-2}{3n},$$
$$b_{n}=\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{7}\cdot\frac{8}{10}\cdots\frac{3n-1}{3n+1},$$
$$c_{n}=\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{8}\cdot\frac{9}{11}\cdots\frac{3n}{3n+2},$$
obviously, $$a_n<b_n<c_n,\quad \forall n=1,2,\cdots,$$
so $$a_n<\sqrt[3]{a_nb_nc_n}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3n+1}\frac{2}{3n+2}}\to0\quad (n\to\infty).$$

Comment: I checked that both $b_n$ and $c_n$ converge to $0$ as well. This is interesting...

Answer (score 2):

You can make it simpler since
$$a_n=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (3i-2) } {\prod_{i=1}^n (3i) }=\frac{\frac{3^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} }{3^n \Gamma (n+1) }=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma (n+1)}$$ Now, almost as usual, take logarithms, use twice Stirling approximation, continue with Taylor to get
$$\log \left(a_n\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)=-\frac{2}{3} \log (n)-\frac{1}{9 n}-\frac{1}{162 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Exponentiate and continue with Taylor using
$$x=e^{\log(x) }$$ to obtain
$$a_n=\frac 1 { \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\,n^{\frac 23}}\left(1-\frac{1}{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)   \right)$$ which is a very good approximation (the relative error is smaller than $0.010$% for $n>3$ and smaller than $0.001$% for $n>7$).

Notice that you can make it much more general

$$A_n=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (a\, n+b) } {\prod_{i=1}^n (c\,n+d) }$$ $$A_n=\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^n\,\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{d}{c}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)}n^{\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}}\left(1+\frac{(b c-a d) (a c+a d+b c)}{2 a^2 c^2 n}   +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method ... Sterling's formula.
As $n \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
(3n-2)!!! &= 
{\frac { {3}^{n}}{\Gamma(1/3)}\Gamma \left( n+{\frac{1}{3}} \right) }
\sim
{\frac {\sqrt{2\pi}\, {{\rm e}^{-n}}}{
\Gamma(1/3)}{3}^{n}{n}^{n-1/6}}
\\
3^n\,n! &\sim 
\sqrt {2\pi}{n}^{n+1/2}{3}^{n}{{\rm e}^{-n}}
\\
\frac{( 3n-2) !!!}{3^{n} \cdotp n!} &\sim
{\frac {1 }{\Gamma(1/3)}{n}^{-2/3}}
\to 0 .
\end{align}